# gdipluspath throws ambiguous byte for cstddef and rpcndr.h

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, gdi+

I am currently updating an ancient program which was last compiled with visual studio 2008. I am updating it (.lib project) to visual studio 2017 for the newest windows sdk (10.0.15063.0), however, the gdiplus library throws an ambiguous symbol error.
More specifically:

```
3>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\um\GdiplusPath.h(145): error C2872: 'byte': ambiguous symbol
3>c:\program files (x86)\windows kits\10\include\10.0.15063.0\shared\rpcndr.h(191): note: could be 'unsigned char byte'
3>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\cstddef(15): note: or 'std::byte'
```

The standard attempts that I have found at this issue unfortunately suppose that the ambiguity error is made by me directly, and not by a new inclusion by visual studio (Which is what I understand cstddef to be?).

So how can I point an external library towards using one symbol definition or the other?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This problem occurs because recent standard introduced `::std::byte` and `::byte` types which will clash with `byte` type defined in `rpcndr.h`:

```
// cstddef
enum class byte : unsigned char {};

// rpcndr.h
typedef unsigned char byte;
```

But that is not the only problem with windows headers, they also introduce `min` and `max` macros (required by gdiplus) that clash with `<limits>` content.

So the workaround would be carefully control how windows and gdi plus headers are included, like this:

```
//  global compilation flag configuring windows sdk headers
//  preventing inclusion of min and max macros clashing with <limits>
#define NOMINMAX 1

//  override byte to prevent clashes with <cstddef>
#define byte win_byte_override

#include <Windows.h> // gdi plus requires Windows.h
// ...includes for other windows header that may use byte...

//  Define min max macros required by GDI+ headers.
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b) (((a) > (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#else
#error max macro is already defined
#endif
#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) (((a) < (b)) ? (a) : (b))
#else
#error min macro is already defined
#endif

#include <gdiplus.h>

//  Undefine min max macros so they won't collide with <limits> header content.
#undef min
#undef max

//  Undefine byte macros so it won't collide with <cstddef> header content.
#undef byte
```

Note that this approach implies that user code never uses `byte`, `min` and `max` from windows sdk headers.

Also `byte` may clash with other third-party libraries.

Comment: Thanks a lot. defining byte as BYTE from minwindef.h solved the issue. 
I have fortunately had control over the definitions from min and max in my own code.

Answer (score 12):

> For Visual Studio, this behavior can be turned off by defining the
>   preprocessor value `_HAS_STD_BYTE` to `0`.

taken from [this article](https://studiofreya.com/2018/01/06/visual-studio-2017-with-cpp17-and-boost/#stdbyte-ambiguous-symbol-and-rpcndr.h).