# Find the dependency path to rpcndr.h

Tags: c++, header-files, dependency-management

I hit compilation error c2872: 'byte' ambiguous symbol in rpcndr.h. However, I couldn't find the dependency path -- how did my code go to rpcndr.h? Is there a way to figure out the hidden link?

Comment: The easiest way to see a complex `#include` hierarchy is to flip the [`/showIncludes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/showincludes-list-include-files) switch on MSVC. It's under _Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Show Includes_

Comment: You probably included Windows.h or something which included it.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45957830/gdipluspath-throws-ambiguous-byte-for-cstddef-and-rpcndr-h) has good discussion about byte and also the dreaded min and max macros.

Comment: @JackC. yeah but i'm not using `gdipluspath` so i'm trying to figure out why my road also crossed `byte`...